# Obtaining values in Java via an AngularJS frontend input box

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

Essentially I have a front end using AngularJS and a back end using Java. I need to be able to send a value from the front end via an input box to the back end to make use of in the Java.

I found a basic example, namely:

Java

```
package com.mkyong.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/user")
public class UserService {

@POST
@Path("/add")
public Response addUser(@FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("age") int age) {

    return Response.status(200)
            .entity("addUser is called, name : " + name    + ", age : " + age)
            .build();

    }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>JAX-RS @FormQuery Testing</h1>

<form action="rest/user/add" method="post" >
<p>Name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>Age : <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand the @FormParam parts and how that works but what I don't understand is how the @Path works as well as the @POST. Is this linked to the form action and is it that simple or is there some step in between?

A general explanation of how this works/if my assertions are correct would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i got from your question you want to more about `@POST` and `@PATH` if yes. than `@POST` is tell you the type of request like `post, get, put, delete` etc. that means your addUser method call only when POST request come to server but path should correct. Now `@PATH` tells you about the URL to call `addUser` method, In your case `@Path("/user") public class UserService` means whenever a request come to /user it call you UserService class, further if we have multiple method in same class like adduser, deleteuser, getuser than you need to tell server which method call for URL so we put @PATH on method and our URL is form.
Example

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
public Response addUser
//URL for aboue method is <baseURL>/user/add
@POST
@Path("/delete")
public Response deleteUser
//URL for above method is <baseURL>/user/delete
```

I hope you under stand the URL mapping in webservice, you need more study about URL mapping in web service.

About `<baseURL>` is also depende upon the web.xml configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note here

1) URL in form action is wrong . It should be /user/add  to

2) You dont have any JS file that mentions about the angular application .

To start a application we need to have something like shown below

```
   var app = angular.module('app',[ 'ngRoute','ngResource']);
```

Comment: URL also depends on `web.xml` configuration, we can not say it is wrong until we saw the web.xml file. And your second point is valide, but he want to more input on @PATH and @POT.